# How to access custom model data in Odoo env using shell command?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am getting key error in the accessing custom model data in shell command. I have added custom addons_path in odoo.conf. For example,

```
addons_path = E:\Odoo\odoogithub\odoo\addons, E:\Odoo\odoogithub\odoo\custom
```

Below I added the exception I got while accessing the custom model.

> > > env['srcil.product'].search([])
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "E:\Odoo\odoogithub\odoo\odoo\api.py", line 473, in **getitem**
> > > return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
> > > File "E:\Odoo\odoogithub\odoo\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 177, in **getitem**
> > > return self.models[model_name]
> > > KeyError: 'srcil.product'

Additionally, I have checked the model in the settings. It is showing fine also I can create data using the create button. [image]

Do I need to add the custom module path or model path anywhere to access the model data?

Comment: when you call the shell, seems that the conf file is not being declared. Use -c to indicate the shell location, or use an alternative conf file for the shell call. Am I right?

Comment: In community edition I put the module in the addons folder. Then it worked fine and I could execute commands. When the module was in custom folder, I wrote the custom module path in the conf file, I was unable to execute shell commands even though the module was showing when I updated the app list.

Comment: What do you've got in the log?

Comment: I have added the logs in the question description. Anyway, it is solved